# Как отменить возможность масштабирования в Google Chrome через multitouch?

Tags: webkit, google-chrome, multi-touch, javascript

Проблему решил для не прокручиваемых страниц добавив обработчик:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length > 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Однако во время прокрутки страницы если случайно коснуться пальцем, то страница масштабируется и вылезает warning: Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

P.S. Google Chrome dasktop'ный

P.P.S. проблему нужно решить для личного использования, не для production.

Answer (score 3):

Решение простое до невозможности:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
    initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```